# Endless GET Response

Tags: spring

I'm trying to learn Table relation in Spring.

Until, addition of `@ManytoOne` in `Product` all were working fine.

Issue arises when I included `@OnetoMany` in `Category`.

Below is what i have done so far, Please refer to this gitlub repository link for a detailed view - https://github.com/sandeepRoy/July2023

Help and Guidance is appreciated. Thank you.

1. Category.java

```
public class Category {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    private String categoryName;
    private String description;
    private String imageUrl;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "category", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    Set<Product> products;

    // getters and setters
    // constructors
}
```

2. Product.java

```
public class Product {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    private String imageUrl;
    private Double price;
    private String description;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "category_id")
    Category category;
    
    // getters and setters
    // constructors
}
```

GET & POST for Products working fine. But for Category, GET just returns an endless json response and I'm not sure what should be the payload for POST. Here are the Swagger Request/Responses

3. GET - Product

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Asus Vivobook 15",
    "imageUrl": "string",
    "price": 29857,
    "description": "Laptop 15inch 8GB DDR-4 1TB HDD Intel Core i3",
    "categoryId": 1
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Asus Zenfone Max",
    "imageUrl": "soon",
    "price": 9780,
    "description": "Phone 5.4inch 3GB RAM 32GB ROM Android 10",
    "categoryId": 2
  }
]
```

4. POST - Product

```
{
  "categoryId": 0,
  "description": "string",
  "id": 0,
  "imageUrl": "string",
  "name": "string",
  "price": 0
}
```

5. POST & GET - Category (Before Adding @OneToMany)

```
{
  "categoryName": "string",
  "description": "string",
  "id": 0,
  "imageUrl": "string"
}
```

6. POST - Category (After adding @OneToMany)

```
{
  "categoryName": "string",
  "description": "string",
  "id": 0,
  "imageUrl": "string",
  "products": [
    {
      "description": "string",
      "id": 0,
      "imageUrl": "string",
      "name": "string",
      "price": 0
    }
  ]
}
```

7. GET - Category (After @OnetoMany)
   Doesn't shows anything in Swagger. In browser it shows as below -

[image: endless GET Response for Category]

Also it shows this error message in console, when i try to do a GET for Category -

```
ERROR 23474 --- 
[nio-8080-exec-8] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : 
Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet]
in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; 
nested exception is org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: Could not write JSON:
Infinite recursion (StackOverflowError);
nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException:
Infinite recursion (StackOverflowError) (through reference chain: com.sandeep.ecommerce.models.Category["products"]->
org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentSet[0]->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should really try to use DTOs instead of publishing your Database entities in an REST Endpoint: https://www.baeldung.com/java-dto-pattern

If you really want this to publish your Entity you can add `@JsonIgnore` above a field to prevent the recursion. In your case it seems to be best suited above the back reference from `Product` to `Category`. Alternatively you could remove the back reference (See https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-ignore-properties-on-serialization)

```
public class Product {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    private String imageUrl;
    private Double price;
    private String description;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "category_id")
    @JsonIgnore // <--------------- this is the added line 
    Category category;

    // getters and setters
    // constructors
}
```

Alternatively you could completely remove the back reference to solve this problem.

Comment: Yes, it seems to working. I can POST a Category without providing the Product List and also create a Product once a Category Id is generated. GET for both works as well and GET of Category shows List of products for each category. Thank you.

Comment: Just a request, if you can provide me a reference material which focuses on these kind of building block, it would be a great help. Bealdung seems more of a experience side.